# link from <p:menuitem> to certain <p:tab>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi guys I want to link from my Menubar to certain Tab, but always the first tab is activated I tried lot of solutions from StackOverflow but nothing works. I think the problems is that i use a preRenderView. I hope someone can help me  :)

I use jsf 2.1 and primefaces 3.5

The code for the menubar

```
  <p:menubar >
       <p:submenu  label="Taskbox" >
            <p:menuitem value="Inbox" url="taskbox.xhtml" />
            <p:menuitem value="Sent" url="taskbox.xhtml#sentTab"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Trash" url="taskbox.xhtml" onclick="tabPanel.select(3)"/>
            <p:menuitem value="New Message" url="#"/>
       </p:submenu>          
    </p:menubar>
```

Der code for the tabs

```
<ui:composition template="/META-INF/templates/templateContentSplit.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="metadata">
            <f:metadata>
                <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{taskboxBean.initPage}" />
            </f:metadata>
        </ui:define>
<ui:define name="metadata">
            <f:metadata>
                <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{taskboxBean.initPage}" />
            </f:metadata>
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="title">
            <h:outputText value="Taskbox" />
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="contentLeft">
            <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <h:form id="postForm">

                <p:tabView id="tabViewPosts" widgetVar="tabPanel">
                    <p:tab title="Inbox" id="inboxTab">
                        <ui:include src="/user/inboxTaskbox.xhtml" />
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="Sent" id="sentTab">
                        <ui:include src="/user/sentTaskbox.xhtml" />
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="Trash" id="trashTab">
                        <ui:include src="/user/trashTaskbox.xhtml" />
                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="contentRight">
            <h:form id="contentForm">
                <ui:include src="/user/detailTaskbox.xhtml" />
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>
```

Comment: Are both (menu and tabs) on the same page?

Comment: i work with templates the top are the menubar and the content the tabs

Comment: Remove the duplicate definition of `ui:define name="metadata"`.

Answer (score 4):

For your `<p:menuitem />` use an `outcome` attribute, which specifies the navigation case, instead of `url`, that's intended to be used with an absolute and not JSF related url. Here you've got a basic explanation case, based in @Daniel Camargo's suggested code:

**tabs.xhtml:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head />

<h:body>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="index" value="#{index}" />
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.initPage}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <h:form>
        <p:menubar>
            <p:submenu label="Taskbox">
                <!-- Different ways of passing the view param -->
                <p:menuitem value="Inbox" outcome="tabs?index=0" />
                <p:menuitem value="Sent" outcome="tabs.xhtml?index=1" />
                <p:menuitem value="Trash" outcome="tabs">
                    <f:param name="index" value="2" />
                </p:menuitem>
                <!-- External url -->
                <p:menuitem value="Google" url="http://www.google.com"
                    target="_blank" />
            </p:submenu>
        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>

    <h:form id="postForm">
        <p:tabView id="tabViewPosts" widgetVar="tabPanel"
            activeIndex="#{index}">
            <p:tab title="Inbox" id="inboxTab">
            A
        </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Sent" id="sentTab">
            B
        </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Trash" id="trashTab">
            C
        </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Note the `outcome` attribute here let's the JSF servlet evaluate the destination url. Basically, an outcome with value of *tabs* will get rendered as *basePath/tabs.xhtml* at client side. So basically you are making the page be directed to itself, but changing the `viewParam` value.

**See also:**

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Comment: what is tab? Now i geht always an     INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR  
org.primefaces.renderkit.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getTargetURL(OutcomeTargetRenderer.java:95)

Comment: You're not specifying your `outcome` properly. Change *tabs* for *taskbox* or whatever your view is named. *tabs* is only the id of my example based in a page called *tabs.xhtml*.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that this is a zero based index. You tabPanel.select(3) will try to activate the 4th tab which doesn't exist. Try doing this:

The menu:

```
<h:form>
    <p:menubar >
        <p:submenu  label="Taskbox" >
            <p:menuitem value="Trash" url="taskbox.xhtml?index=2"/>
        </p:submenu>          
    </p:menubar>
</h:form>
```

The Taskbox page:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="index" value="#{viewMBean.index}" />
</f:metadata>

<h:form id="postForm">
    <p:tabView id="tabViewPosts" widgetVar="tabPanel" activeIndex="#{viewMBean.index}">
        <p:tab title="Inbox" id="inboxTab">
            A
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Sent" id="sentTab">
            B
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Trash" id="trashTab">
            C
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

Comment: So they are not on the same page I believe.

Comment: Is  viewMBean an independent Bean ?

Comment: It's a view scoped bean with a integer property called index.